# Updating Day Light Saving time properties for JDK 1.6

Tags: java, dst

How and where to update **JDK 1.6**, Daylight Saving Time properties ? Kindly provide me a solution for both windows and linux platforms.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Please include a code example.

Comment: We need more information.

Comment: While fetching System time, java will return time based on its time  zone taking day light saving time into account.. What I have to do to get time based on day light saving.??

Comment: Are you looking for the Java Control Panel? (Linux: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/enable_console_linux.xml) (Windows: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/win_controlpanel.xml)

Comment: NO I'm speaking about **Daylight saving time**

Answer (score 2):

For Linux, the timezone data for OpenJDK Java is provided (typically) by the "tzdata-java" package (or a similarly named package ... depending on your distro).  Make sure that you have the most recent version of that package installed.

Alternatively, read this Oracle page about the "tzupdater" tool.  This provides a system independent method for updating the timezone info in an installed Oracle JDK or JRE:

- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzupdater-readme-136440.html